# WordPress issues: Deprecated and admin not opening

Tags: php, wordpress

I moved to a new server and the site is opening with theme and everything
the wp-admin is not opening
in the home page which is opening, I am getting in the top these error line:

```
Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in /home/example/public_html/example/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1409
```

and

```
Warning: copy(/home/OLDurl/public_html/folderName/wp-content/uploads/redux/google-fonts/googlefonts.html): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/new/public_html/example/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-filesystem-direct.php on line 21
```

---

Admin page isn't opening at all giving this:

```
Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in /home/example/public_html/example/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1409
```

and

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/example/public_html/folder/wp-includes/wp-db.php:1409) in /home/example/public_html/folder/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1173
```

Answer (score 0):

lol it is the second time for me here and my second time answering my own questions

well, for any one having similar issue, just remove the wp-debug from htaccess

but I advise u to re-install a fresh copy of wordpress and it might have issues